# Return a value present from recursive function in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to extract a value from a while loop. In the output, I am able to capture the value in the `Else` statement but not able to return it when it is in the console log from the main statement. I want to be able to return "103" when I call the `getValueFromkey()` function.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Tesst {
    
static String line = "", str = "";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filepath = "C:/Users/Navi/Downloads/sample.xml";
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }
        
        br.close();

        JSONObject jsondata = XML.toJSONObject(str);
        
        System.out.println("From main: " + getValueFromKey(jsondata, "routing_bic"));
    }

    private static Integer getValueFromKey(JSONObject json, String key) {
        boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKeys;
        Integer foundKey = 0;

        if(!exists) {
            keys = json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                // Store next Key in nextKeys
                nextKeys = (String)keys.next();
                
                try {
                    // Check if the given Key is a JSON Object
                    if(json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        // If Key does not exist
                        if(!exists) {
                            // Recursive function call
                            getValueFromKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                        }
                    } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonArrayString = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            JSONObject innerJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArrayString);
                            
                            // Recursive function call
                            if(!exists) {
                                getValueFromKey(innerJsonObject.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If key exists, print value
            foundKey += parseObject(json, key);
            System.out.println("From loop: " + foundKey);
            return foundKey;
        }
//      System.out.println("Found Key = " + foundKey);
        return 1; // Return 1 when key not found
    }
    
    private static Integer parseObject(JSONObject json, String key) {
        System.out.println("From parseObject = " + json.get(key));
        return (Integer) json.get(key);
    }
    
}
```

Sample XML

```
<Test>
    <BIBRq>
        <UserId>123</UserId>
        <CIFNo>123</CIFNo>
        <CompanyId>asd</CompanyId>
        <LegalId>123</LegalId>
        <LegalIdType>ABC</LegalIdType>
        <LegalIdCountry>ABC</LegalIdCountry>
    </BIBRq>
    <SubSvcRq>
        <SubSvc>
            <SubSvcRqHeader>
                <SvcCode>ABCD</SvcCode>
                <SubSvcSeq>1</SubSvcSeq>
                <TxnRef>12345</TxnRef>
                <ClientUserID/>
            </SubSvcRqHeader>
            <SubSvcRqDetail>
                <ft_tnx_record>
                    <additional_field>
                        <account_details>
                            <routing_bic>103</routing_bic>
                        </account_details>
                    </additional_field>
                </ft_tnx_record>
            </SubSvcRqDetail>
        </SubSvc>
    </SubSvcRq>
</Test>
```

Output:

From parseObject = 103

From loop: 103

From main: 1

Comment: If you want to return only a single value, then why the return type of the function is ArrayList. Also, when you call the function recursively, you should return its value. You are not using the return value from recursive calls anywhere.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Thanks for replying. I've made the necessary changes. I'm not sure I should be returning the value through the recursive calls.

Comment: `1` is an odd value to return for "not found" (and I don't mean "odd" in the mathematical sense)

Comment: @knittl I agree, it's a temporary placeholder until I find something more reasonable to replace it.

Comment: I agree with first comment and answer, but probably there is also too many `if(!exists)` tests where the value of `exists` does not seem to be updated accordingly.

Comment: I actually got the above code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjZqLUGCWxo to test out the function. However, it is only in the console log and I want to get it to return the value instead.

Comment: @NaviHog if you step through the function with a debugger, which path does it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. I notice that you recursively call the function `getValueFromKey`. That will never work if you don't assign the variable `foundKey` with the return value of the recursive invocation.
   So, just change each recursive calls in this:

   foundKey = getValueFromKey(..., key);
2. In addition, the last statement `return 1` is wrong, because it will override any possible value returned by the subsequent recursive invocation. So, in replacement, you have to return always the `foundKey` variable.

I slightly changed your code and tested it with your sample file and it works fine. Differently than yours, I also wrapped the `BufferedReader` with try-with-resouce block, which I always prefer to simple try-catch, because it garantees that it closes the stream for you, even in case of exceptions.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Test {
    
    static String line = "", str = "";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\marco\\Downloads\\sample.xml";
        
        try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)); ) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                str += line;
            }
        }

        JSONObject jsondata = XML.toJSONObject(str);
        
        System.out.println("From main: " + getValueFromKey(jsondata, "routing_bic"));
    }

    private static Integer getValueFromKey(JSONObject json, String key) {
        boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKeys;
        Integer foundKey = 0;

        if(!exists) {
            keys = json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                // Store next Key in nextKeys
                nextKeys = (String)keys.next();
                
                try {
                    // Check if the given Key is a JSON Object
                    if(json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        // If Key does not exist
                        if(!exists) {
                            // Recursive function call
                            foundKey = getValueFromKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                        }
                    } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonArrayString = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            JSONObject innerJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArrayString);
                            
                            // Recursive function call
                            if(!exists) {
                                foundKey = getValueFromKey(innerJsonObject.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If key exists, print value
            foundKey += parseObject(json, key);
            System.out.println("From loop: " + foundKey);
        }
//      System.out.println("Found Key = " + foundKey);
        return foundKey; // Return 1 when key not found
    }
    
    private static Integer parseObject(JSONObject json, String key) {
        System.out.println("From parseObject = " + json.get(key));
        return (Integer) json.get(key);
    }
    
}
```

And here is the output:

```
From parseObject = 103
From loop: 103
From main: 103
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track. But even then, the result shouldn't be `null`, but one of `0` (the inital value of the Integer), `1` (the fallback/default return value), or – least likely – the real value

Comment: @knittl you're right, apologies on that. It is in fact 1.

Comment: @Marco Tizzano I've tried your suggestion, but it still returns `1`.

Comment: @NaviHog I added the fixed code, i was actually right, but there was also another error which compromised the result. I added everything in the answer.

Comment: `json.getInt(key)` would be better than `(Integer)json.get(key)`

Comment: @sprinter you are right. I didn't want to touch that much his code, he will get there eventually, but rather I focused on giving him a solution for the unexpected result.

Comment: @NaviHog btw don't forget to change the `filepath` variable. As you can see in my code there is still a path from my file system :)

Comment: @MarcoTizzano Hi Marco, thanks for helping out! It worked for the sample xml that I've provided. It is a distilled version of the actual xml, but when I apply it back to the actual XML file, it did not work as expected. I've updated the XML with the full details.

Comment: @NaviHog you're welcome. If you are happy with the answer, please accept it, so it can help other developers in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoTizzano Hi Marco, the code doesn't seem to work with the newly updated XML. Perhaps you might want to test it with the new XML? Thank you!

Comment: @NaviHog I'm trying to be helpful, but in my humble opinion this is going a bit beyond the purpose of the question. My intention was to help you to fix the issue with the recursive call, I was not suppose to write the whole program. Anyway, if your code doesn't work with the newly XML, you must have missed some cases, have you tried to debug and check what's missing there? I am not sure I have time to review the whole program and provide you with a fully working solution. I can possibly later on.

Comment: @MarcoTizzano Gladly appreciate your time. I'll mark your solution as the answer.